# How to execute method once for certain data value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a web app that goes through steps showing different content. I have a value of 'data: 0' in my data property and is incremented every time the next button is hit. A user is able to go back in steps to make changes if needed.

What I'm trying to do is have a method fire once when it hits a certain step. Can I use v-on:change to check for this specific data value and if so where would I place that handler? This method should only be fired the first time it hits the specific step to avoid issues when a user goes back.

```
data: {

 addedKeywords: false,
 newAds:[
  []
  ]
 },
 methods: {
 baseAds(){
  if(this.step3Base == false){
    this.newAds[0].push({
      id: 0,
      headline1: 'Headline 1',
      headline2: 'Headline 2',
      headline3: 'headline3',
      desc1: 'This is your description 1',
      desc2: 'This is your description 2',
      finalurl: 'www.finalURL.com',
      path1: '',
      path2: '',
      boolean: true
    })
    for(var x = 1; x < this.options.length; x++){
      this.newAds.push([]);
    }
  }
  this.step3Base = true;
 },
 restOfAds (){
  var length = this.options.length
  if(this.addedKeywords === false){
    for(var x = 1; x < length; x++){
      this.newAds[x].push({
        id: x,
        headline1: 'New',

      })
    }
    this.addedKeywords = true;
  }
 },
 lengthInput: function (){

  return this.options.length

}
},
watch: {
lengthInput: function(oldlength, newLength){
  if(newLength > oldlength && this.addedKeywords != false){
    for(var x = oldLength; x < newLength; x++){
      this.newAds.push([{
        id: x,
        headline1: 'New',

      }])
    }
  }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use watchers [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers] tp listen to changes in the value of a data variable and run a specific function when the `steps` reach a specified value. You can also create some `flag` variable and set it appropriately to prevent the function getting triggered again.

Comment: I created a watch property but the function does not execute. I've checked the values with dev tools and the length of user input does change and also the flag variable 'addedKeywords' changes to the proper value that I check for in the watch function. Am i setting something up wrong that it doesn't not fire? I edited the post to show the new code

Comment: @LuisRodriguez you are using a function instead of variable. Please check the documentation again. And consider creating a new question instead of modifying the entire question :)

Comment: The question changed from what it was initially stated and creates a problem for the entire community which might later refer this and would be confused with the answer.